# Select image pixels of a certain colour

Tags: image-processing

[`PixelValuePositions[image, colour, distance]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PixelValuePositions.html) returns the positions of pixels within a certain "distance" of a given colour.

- Is there an equivalent function that returns a binary mask instead of a list of positions? A list of positions is slow to work with. I am looking to produce a mask to achieve better performance.
- What exactly is the meaning of `distance` here in the case of colour images?

Comment: Have you considered `ColorDetect[image, ColorsNear[colour, distance]]`? You can also specify the colour distance metric (see `ColorsNear` documentation). I suspect the default distance is the same as in `ColorDistance`.

Comment: @kirma I didn't know this function, thanks! It returns a grey image, not a binary one. The meaning of the grey level is not 100% clear. It does not simply identify colours closer to `c` than `d`.

Comment: It's not clear what I should do if I wanted all pixels closer to `colour` than a distance `d`. Sure, I can `Binarize` the output, but that's naive. The docs don't seem to tell me what the meaning of the grey level is.

Comment: What about `ColorDistance` and then `Binarize`? In this case you know what the gray level means.

Comment: @Szabolcs You can file a documentation bug on that... ;)